# I have a question about the gravity probe B geodectic precession formula and why it seems to be twice the planetary precession formula

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, orbital-motion, precession, space-mission

Specifically, I can work out the planetary precession formula to give radians per orbit as

6*pi*GM/c^2r

(and I find that on the web at places like http://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/336k/Newtonhtml/node116.html , equation 1028).  I can use that formula for all the planets and match published data.

When I use that formula for the gravity probe B precession, I use G= 6.67e-11m3/kgs2, M = 5.97e24 kg, c= 3e8 m/s, and r= 7,013,000 m, I get a precession angle of 11.92e-8 rads/orbit, which is exactly twice the published 5.96e-9 rads/orbit.

I do find at Wikipedia under the geodectic effect the equation that the precession angle for a satellite is approximately 3*pi*m/r where m= GM/c^2. That is

3*pi*GM/c^2r

or half the other formula, and agrees with my finding that we seem to have two different precession equations "out there" for planets versus satellites, and the formulas result in a factor of two difference.

Is there some simple interpretation issue here?  Is precession defined in some way that the term means different things for planets than it does for satellites?

Comment: Please mark up your math using mathjax.

Answer (score 1):

These two precessions are apples and oranges, and there is no reason to expect them to be exactly equal.

The precession of Mercury is derived theoretically by considering a non-spinning point particle moving on a geodesic in the Sun’s gravity. Its orbit is an almost-ellipse whose perihelion slowly precesses around the Sun.

The precession measured by Gravity Probe B is the precession of the angular momentum of a spinning gyroscope in orbit. The geodetic part of this precession is derived theoretically by considering how a *vector* is transported along a geodesic in curved spacetime.

So the latter has to do with vector transport through curved spacetime, and the former has nothing to do with vector transport.

Comment: There's probably some kind of combination of parameters in the PPN formalism that determines the magnitude of these two effects.  It'd be interesting to know whether these two effects are related in a 2:1 ratio in any metric theory, or if that ratio only holds in GR.

Comment: I appreciate the answer but I'm not satisfied.  GP-B's precession is independent of any parameters related to the spinning gyroscope.  At least in terms of the formula, you get the same result whether GB-P's spin velocity is double or zero.  Plus if you found that the price of apples is exactly twice that of oranges in every store in the universe, you'd conclude that there is a correlation.  I suspect the answer is related to the fact that the satellite's precession is as of 2π as measured by a distant observer, while the planet's is as of 2π as measured by the orbiter.

Comment: Both precessions depend only on $M$ and $r$ and not on other parameters because they are curvature effects. By dimensional analysis they have to be proportional to $GM/c^2r$ and therefore have some dimensionless ratio. I suggest that you pursue Michael Seifert’s suggestion of finding out what their formulas are in the PPN formalism. If the ratio is exactly 2 in all possible metric theories, then it would be interesting to understand why. Otherwise, I don’t think your idea could be the explanation.